# ModuleNotFoundError on jenkins build cannot be replicated locally

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, pyinstaller

**Running an exe file which gives the below error on win10 build agent but not when the same script is ran on win10 locally:**

```
16:06:50  Traceback (most recent call last):
16:06:50    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
16:06:50    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
16:06:50    File "package.py", line 98, in <module>
16:06:50    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_venv\lib\site-packages\testing_framework_sdk\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
16:06:50  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_case_sdk'
```

Both files are ran from the same downloaded package with no changes in contents between the two.
Script does not require additional programs such as Python in order to operate.

Given that library files(.pyc) are contained within the downloaded directory I assume that this exe was generated using pyinstaller. python36.dll is also contained within the downloaded package

**I don't have access to the source for this exe.**

The file test_case_sdk.pyc does exist in the same directory for both the jenkins agent and local machine.

Do anyone know what is causing this discrepancy?

Edit: Turns out the filepath to test_case_sdk exceeded windows default limit of 260, this was why the module could not be found. I condensed the file path, error has gone.

Comment: Looks like a python module is missing, maybe it is missing only on the win build agent

Comment: @Chelmy88, both executables are running from exactly the same directory with the same contents.